# Solve $\frac d{dx}W_{-1}(-1/x)=-1$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

This problem arose when I tried to find the maximum of $f(x)=\ln(x\ln(x\ln(x\cdots)))-x$. This can be written as $f(x)=\exp(-W_{-1}(-1/x))/x -x$ by substituting the recursion into $f$. The negative branch of $W$ is taken as $-1/x$ is negative for all positive real $x$. Now $$f'(x)=(x-x^2\exp(W_{-1}(-1/x)))^{-1}-1$$ and equating to zero yields $x-x^2\exp(W_{-1}(-1/x))=1$ for stationary points. Notice that $\exp(W_{-1}(-1/x))=-\frac1{xW_{-1}(-1/x)}$ so this is equivalent to $$x+\frac x{W_{-1}(-1/x)}=1\implies-\frac{W_{-1}(-1/x)}{x(W_{-1}(-1/x)+1)}=-1$$ LHS is the derivative of $W_{-1}(-1/x)$ so this leaves us with $\frac d{dx}W_{-1}(-1/x)=-1$. How to continue?

Comment: This is equivalent to solving $u^2e^u+u=1$, which can’t be solved analytically even with Lambert W.

Comment: From the graph it seems that $W_{-1}'(z) < -7.4$, approximately, for all $z$ such that $W_{-1}(z)$ is real.  So it is never $-1$.

Comment: @GEdgar Are you sure? I get a value of $x=2.990...$

Comment: You get $x=2.99\dots$ for $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[ W_{-1}\left(\frac{-1}{x}\right)\right],$$ which is not the same as $$W_{-1}'\left(\frac{-1}{x}\right)$$.

Comment: $f'(-1/x)$ means $(d/dz) f(z)$, where $z=-1/x$.  That is not the same as $(d/dx)[f(-1/x)]$. For example,  $(d/dx) \sin(-1/x) \ne \cos(-1/x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Via [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem):

$\def\W{\operatorname W}$
$$\frac d{dx}\left(-\W_{-1}\left(-\frac1x\right)-x\right)=0\implies x=-\frac{e^{-u}}u,e^uu^2+u+1=0,u=-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}e^{nu}u^{2n}}{du^{n-1}}\right|_{-1}$$

then [General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) uses [Laguerre $\operatorname L_v^a(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=LaguerreL):

$$\boxed{x=-\frac{e^{-u}}u,u=-1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\operatorname L_{n-1}^{n+1}(n)}{ne^n}}$$

[giving](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E-u%2F-u%2Cu%3D-1-sum%5Be%5E%28-n%29%2Fn+LaguerreL%5B-1+%2B+n%2C+1+%2B+n%2C+n%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C90%7D%5D) your maximum at $x=2.9902\dots$

Comment: The coefficients can also contain $\frac{d^{n-1}}{du^{n-1}}\left(\frac{e^{-u}}u\right) e^{un}u^{2n}$ to have $x=a+\sum\dots$. Maybe we can use this and the integral representation of $L_v(x)$ to get an integral solution for $x$?

Answer (score 1):

$$x=-\frac{e^{-u}}{u}=-\frac{1}{ue^u},\ \ u^2e^u+u+1=0$$
$$u^2e^u+u+1=0\tag{1}$$

We see, equation (1) is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($u,e^u$). The main theorem in [Ritt 1925] cannot help in these cases: We cannot read an [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) inverse function over a non-discrete domain directly from the equation because we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $u$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

We also see, equation (1) is an irreducible algebraic equation of both $u$ and $e^u$. According to the theorems in [Lin 1983] and [Chow 1999], assuming Schanuel's conjecture is true, such kind of equations cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) or explicit elementary numbers respectively.

$$\frac{u^2}{u+1}e^u=-1$$

We see, this equation cannot be solved in terms of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) but in terms of Generalized Lambert W:

$$\frac{u^2}{u-(-1)}e^u=-1$$
$$u=W\left(^{0\ 0}_{-1};-1\right)$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{W\left(^{0\ 0}_{-1};-1\right)e^{W\left(^{0\ 0}_{-1};-1\right)}}$$

So we have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $x$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.
$\ $

[[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/)

[[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165)

[[Chow 1999] Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)